# building kernel cause dependency cycle error

Tags: kernel

I was trying to compile latest kernel with some edits.

while doing `sudo make modules_install`

```
 INSTALL virt/lib/irqbypass.ko

  DEPMOD  4.4.0-rc1+

depmod: WARNING: found 2 modules in dependency cycles!
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/4.4.0-rc1+/kernel/drivers/staging/lustre/lnet/lnet/lnet.ko in dependency cycle!
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/4.4.0-rc1+/kernel/drivers/staging/lustre/lustre/libcfs/libcfs.ko in dependency cycle!
./scripts/depmod.sh: line 57:  1471 Killed                  "$DEPMOD" "$@" "$KERNELRELEASE" $SYMBOL_PREFIX
make: *** [_modinst_post] Error 137
```

What is the reason for this?
How do I fix this?

Edit:

I have done the following changes in the kernel to add a new syscall for learning purpose

**Makefile**

```
core-y          += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ hello/
```

added hello/ folder

**syscall_64.tbl**

```
546 x32 hello           sys_hello
```

**syscall.h**

```
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void);
```

**Makefile**

```
obj-y:= hello.o
```

**hello.c**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)
{
    printk("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The actual reason for the failure is the `Killed` bit. Most often this is OOM killer killing it due to lack of RAM. How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: @jordanm: 4GB .

Comment: Does `dmesg` show that OOM killer was invoked?

Comment: @jordanm: dmesg shows out of memory error. What do I need to do now? 4GB+2GB swap is not enough?

Comment: @jordanm: oom_kill_process

Comment: @jordanm `depmod` doesn't normally need a lot of memory. It's probably caught in a loop due to the dependency cycles.

Comment: Assuming you didn't change the source, this is probably a bug, you should report it if it hasn't been reported already. Be sure to say exactly how you configured the kernel (`.config` file). In the meantime, use a released version rather than a beta version.

Comment: @Gilles: I added a  new syscall for learning purpose. I will add that in question.

Comment: Did it compile before? If not, start from a kernel that does compile. (Always compile and run once before you start patching.) If it did, make sure you've listed all the changes you made, and ask for help on [so] — this site is for users and administrators, we don't do programming questions. And, once again, your `.config` is necessary. By the way, as a learning exercise, adding a syscall is pretty useless — that hardly ever happens. Almost all functionality comes via a driver that's invoked by `open`/`read`/`write`/`close` or `open`/`ioctl`/`close` or `socket`/….

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this same problem as of today, while trying to compile the net-next kernel.

My searching yielded an answer from here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.lustre.devel/4032

The Lustre module is causing the dependency problem, and the developer behind it should have produced and pushed a patch by now, but it appears that patch hasn't made it in to the net-next (or main kernel) rc trees.

There are two possible workarounds for this if you do not require Lustre:

1. According to the post linked above, and by my own experience, removing the offending code is an option.  If you edit drivers/staging/lustre/lustre/libcfs/module.c (from the directory where the kernel source sits) and search for `IOC_LIBCFS_PING_TEST`, you can delete that entire case block.  (If you are unfamiliar with C code, delete all the way down to the line with the next occurrence of `return 0;`)

   This is what I did, and I was able to install the modules after recompiling.
2. Edit the .config file: Your .config likely specifies that various Lustre components should be compiled as modules.  Edit the .config in the root of the kernel directory, and search for the line

   `CONFIG_LUSTRE_FS=m`

Change the "m" to "n" and this should prevent the module from being compiled.  I have not tested this as a fix myself.

You can also wait until this patch makes it into the kernel source, but it's already been about a month.